# How to Scrape from nestled Divs using VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

[HTML code from website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws4FU.png)

Hi All,

I am trying to write a web scraper to scrape information and ultimately download files hosted on the site (although I do not think I will solve this issue here. It is BIM360, an Autodesk site that hosts files and information relevant to the files. Here is what I have so far: it opens the website but then I met with error 924. I think this is because there are nestled divs as per the picture. I have highlighted what I am trying to scrape initially in the picture, I then wish it to loop down the page and do this for each document. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
Sub GetIEValues()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
Dim dd As Variant

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://docs.b360.eu.autodesk.com/projects/f0c33551-e503-4f82-afe8-de994c61b880/reviews"

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:016"))

    Do
        DoEvents
        Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE


    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(lRow, "A").Value = Now()
        .Cells(lRow, "B").Value = .document.getElementsByClassName("EllipsisText MatrixTable__row-cell-text")(0).innerText
        .Cells(lRow, "C").Value = .document.getElementsByClassName("EllipsisText MatrixTable__row-cell-text")(1).innerText
        .Cells(lRow, "D").Value = .document.getElementsByClassName("EllipsisText MatrixTable__row-cell-text")(2).innerText
        .Cells(lRow, "E").Value = .document.getElementsByClassName("EllipsisText MatrixTable__row-cell-text")(3).innerText
        .Cells(lRow, "F").Value = .document.getElementsByClassName("EllipsisText MatrixTable__row-cell-text")(4).innerText
    End With
     .Quit
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Please add the actual error description and indicate on which line it occurs.

Comment: Hi @Qharr thanks for the comment: Error is - 

_Run time error 462: The remote server does not exist or is not available._ 

and `Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE ` is highlighted.

Comment: Could be a security settings problem. Have you tried using InternetExplorerMedium object instead of InteretExplorer?

Comment: @QHarr In line 3 I am using InternetExplorerMedium. I think the problem is with the code of trying to get the embedded DIv Classes. I will try scrape something else to verify it is not the internet explorer

Comment: pretty sure it is not about the embedded divs. That info would already be loaded. Your error seems to indicate either wrong url or url blocked by security settings/firewall.

Comment: How are your IE security settings set? What level?